# QuickLook for images in iPhone

Tags: iphone, quicklook

I am downloading a image knowing the url of the image . Now how can i view this image using a quick look frame work. I am using the following codes to download.

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  
URLWithString:@"http://good-wallpapers.com/pictures/3048/frosty_apple_logo_iphone.jpg"]]];
```

What should i do to quickLook if i have an array or dictonary of UIImages like wise..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An UIimageview in  scroll view is fine to show all images . Below is loading all images from array to UIimageView in a UIscrollview

```
for (UIView *v in [scrollView subviews]) {
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}

CGRect workingFrame = scrollView.frame;
workingFrame.origin.x = 0;

for(id datavalue in tableList) {

    UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:datavalue];
    imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:downloadedImage];
    [imageview.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
    [imageview.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
    [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    imageview.frame = workingFrame;
    [scrollView addSubview:imageview];
    [imageview release];

    workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;
}

[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(workingFrame.origin.x, workingFrame.size.height)];
```

where tablelist is a collection of image data.